# How to close H2 SQL with all it's background threads (MVStore)

Tags: java, h2

During memory allocation optimization process for Java application that use embedded H2SQL v1.4.196 i noticed that even after closing all H2 database connections (via 'Connection.close()') and even after trying to execute 'SHUTDOWN' statement, there is still one background H2 thread running - "MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread". If i understand correctly - it's a H2's key-value storage engine.

[5 sec memory allocation profiling screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fxgL.png)

How can i correctly close that remaining H2 SQL thread? All active database connections have been long closed by that moment.

The way database is opened and closed in application:

```
connString = "jdbc:h2:file:" + dbFilename + ";TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0;PAGE_SIZE=1024;LOG=0;CACHE_SIZE=8192;UNDO_LOG=0";
dbActiveConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connString, "","");

// Do something

dbActiveConnection.createStatement().execute("SHUTDOWN");
dbActiveConnection.close();

// Rest of work without any database access
// Even after 10 minutes, H2's background thread still running
```

Comment: Which version of the H2 database do you use? (Please edit your question and add it)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that i missed it, added.